# ListBuilder with StreamBuilder not returning results

Tags: listview, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot, stream-builder

I have a StreamBuilder which has a ListBuilder within it. I can see from my print statements that the Stream is returning data, but when I try to see the length it doesn't appear to be working

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream: commentsRef
                  .doc(widget.task.id)
                  .collection('taskComments')
                  .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                print('Has error: ${snapshot.hasError}');
                print('Has data: ${snapshot.hasData}');
                print('Snapshot Data ${snapshot.data}');
                print('Connection State ${snapshot.connectionState}');
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      print(widget.task.id);
                      Comment comment =
                          Comment.fromDoc(snapshot.data.docs[index]);
                      return _buildComment(comment);
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  return Center(
                      child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text('No questions have been asked yet'),
                      Text('Be the first to ask a question'),
                    ],
                  ));
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Category>> snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Something went wrong');
  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
    return Text('Loading');

  print(snapshot.data.docs.length);
  // confirm that the length above has a value
  if (snapshot.data.docs.length > 0) {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        print(widget.task.id);
        Comment comment = Comment.fromDoc(snapshot.data.docs[index]);
        return _buildComment(comment);
      },
    );
  } else {
    return Center(
        child: Column(
      children: [
        Text('No questions have been asked yet'),
        Text('Be the first to ask a question'),
      ],
    ));
  }
});
```

Comment: yeah doesnt really help as the docs.length is still 0 yet there is data

Comment: Print this lets see the result. print(snapshot.data.size);print(snapshot.data.docs.map((e) => e.data()));